# Paginating through a cached search query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get the data from a query paginated, from a cached copy of a query?

When searching, we get 10 results (max) by default.
We can also specify "size", and "from".

However, (looking at a trivial query, just to make it simpler) I wonder, if I paginate so:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "from": 10,
  "size": 10
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "from": 20,
  "size": 10
}'
```

is the query executed each time on the server, and then a "page" is returned? Or is the query cached and executed only the first time?

I could see a use for both usecases:

1. If it is executed anew each time, this will reflect changes to documents that might happen.
2. If it is cached, it will create a lot less of a load on the server. Specifically this can be used to create a "streaming" from the server to some "reducer" on the client side. (In that case, I would expect the query to return a link to the next page).

How can I enforce these two cases. Which one is the default?

Also, what would happen if my query would run a sorting script? for example:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "Math.random()",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/index1/type1/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "Math.random()",
      "type": "number",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "from": 10,
  "size": 10
}'
```

will the random sort be applied twice (so I might get some items appearing in both queries)? How do I prevent that and "lock" the query to pagination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two year old question, unanswered. I'm answering because I hate coming across unanswered questions and I'm doing my bit.

A feature that ElasticSearch offers is the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) (available back to [v0.9](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-request-scroll.html) and still available in 1.5 with little changes)

This feature allows you to store a cached query result set (default expiry is 1 minute). Unless you make another follow up query within this 1m the query result set will be sent to the shards for a newer version.

This is very handy when you have a lot of live and moving data. Particularly useful when you're migrating data to/from indexes during a migration or update of mapping.